# How to convert NSAttributedString (with image) into HTML?

Tags: html, ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I know how to convert the common `NSAttributedString` (which has no image) into HTML. I set the Images as `NSTextAttachment` to `NSAttributedString` (these attributed strings are set as `attributeText` of a `UITextView`). How could I convert the whole attributed string into HTML?

I‘ve found an answer [related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583127/4875807),which mentions:

> Simple idea for image: encode it with base64 and put it directly in a < img > tag with the right frame.

But how could i implement that?

Comment: you implement that?.I fetch same issue.

Comment: got any solution, @GamiNilesh, please put solution if you find any

Comment: @MehulThakkar No,If You get please put answer.

Comment: No, I haven't find any solution, finally i moved with https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor to get my things done.